# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that $AB$ is invertible. Prove A and B are invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that $AB$ is invertible.
>
> 1. Prove that $A$ and $B$ are invertible.
> 2. Give an example to show a product of nonsquare matrices can be invertible even though the factors are not.

1. If $AB$ is invertible, then there exists $(AB)^{-1}$ such that $(AB)(AB)^{-1}=I_n$.
   So we find inverses for both $A$ and $B$, hence $A$ and $B$ are invertible.
2. Let
   $$
       A=\begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 0 \\
       0 & 1 & 0 \\
       \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   and
   $$
       B=\begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 1 \\
       0 & 1  \\
       1 & 0  \\
       \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   Then $AB$ is invertible while $A$ and $B$ are not.

Is it fine?

Comment: In (a) you are not showing anything. How do you find the inverses for $A$ and $B$ ? Also, (b) is fine!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* See also the section on titles in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) (The part entitled "Make your title your question" is especially relevant to this.)

Comment: In (b), what is a non-invertible nonsquare matrix? If it means "not full rank" then $A$ and $B$ are not valid.

Comment: Are you saying that $A^{-1}$ exists because $(AB)^{-1}$ exists? That's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints.** Let $E$ be a square matrix. Then, the following are equivalent:

$\rm (a)$ $E$ is invertible.

$\rm (b)$ The only solution for $E\vec{x} = \vec0$ is $\vec{x} = \vec0$.

$\rm (c)$ For any vector $\vec y$, there exists a vector $\vec x$ such that $\vec{y} = E\vec{x}$.

Now, use $\rm (b)$ to show that $B$ is invertible, and use $\rm (c)$ to show that $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

If you know some things about determinants: if $AB = I$ then

$$\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)=\det(I)=1$$

So, $\det(A),\det(B)\neq 0$ and so both are invertible.

Answer (score 1):

For Part 1, think about how you might use the fact that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ to prove that statement in a more rigorous fashion.

Part 2 looks good.